# How to draw a 2D grid or a map on a web page?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I am trying to draw a 2D grid on a web page. Where I can color individual cell. Any example code to do that?

Also if there is a way of doing it then I also want to know how to resize it or to zoom in and out.

Thanks

Comment: What about a straightforward table?

Comment: @Hidde: Bring on the CSS brigade.

Comment: have you looked at html5 and canvas ?

Comment: I am new to all this.

Comment: I cant use a table. This grid is going to be used to display like a map where I will color points to display a path.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of 2d grid do you want to draw and why?
You could just use a table.

```
<style>
.black {
background:#000;
}
.grey {
background:#ccc;
}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="black"></td><td class="grey"></td><td class="black"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

etc

Comment: This grid is going to be used to display like a map where I will color points to display a path. OR any suggestion you can provide to do it a better way

Comment: Well aside from the obvious table method as I mentioned,

There's always canvas? Which is more complicated and might be unnecessary.

Comment: I am new to web development. I can look into canvas.

Comment: Cool, ok just google "draw with canvas"
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-draw-with-html-5-canvas

It's really easy when you get to know it!